# When I type sudo apt-get update I get:

Tags: apt, update

When I type sudo apt-get update I get:

```
Repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'stable' N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

In return?

I have only just bought the raspberry pi and this is new to me so if anyone knows can you just take some time to answer my question? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After looking this up for hours I have found the answer of just typing: Sudo apt get update with no dashes and then typing Y - Yes - and that worked! 
Hope this could help some people.
-Seth :)

Comment: If you are running updates from the command line (i.e. manually) it is better to use apt rather than apt-get.  Apt gives more prompts and help where as apt-get is more designed for scripts.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.